# Google Sites API - Java - Getting a Content Feed using GoogleCredential

Tags: java, google-sites

Desperately hoping someone can help.

I am using the gdata library (Java), together with Oauth2 and the GoogleCredential object, to return a SiteFeed of my personal Google Site (not within an Apps domain). The SiteFeed is returned fine.

I now want to use the same GoogleCredential to retrieve the ContentFeed for that same site. The trouble is, the feed seems to be blank. I have no other messages.

Here's what I have done:

1. Opened the dev console
2. Created a project
3. Created a service account
4. Downloaded the P12 file for the service account
5. Enabled a suite of API's for the project
6. Set my service account user to have delegated authority
7. On my Google site I have granted the same service account user 'owner' permissions to my site root

This should mean that the service user can basically do anything (I think).

In my Java class I:

1. Create a GoogleCredential object and add it to the SitesService object

   ```
   static SitesService service;       
   public static void setSiteAuthenticationService(...all string values...){
      SITES_FEED_URL = new URL(urlString);
      File p12 = new File(p12Location);   
      HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
      JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
      String[] SCOPESArray = {scopeUrl};
      final List SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SCOPESArray);

      GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
          .setTransport(httpTransport)
          .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
          .setServiceAccountId(accountId)
          .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
          .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(p12)
          .build();

   service = new SitesService("pgts-search");
   service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
   //service.useSsl();
   service.setConnectTimeout(120000);  
   }
   ```
2. Call to get the Site Feed using the authenticated service (this works)

   ```
   siteFeed = service.getFeed(SITES_FEED_URL, SiteFeed.class);
   ```
3. Call to get the Site Content Feed using the same authenticated service (this doesn't work)

   ```
   //iterate over the site entries
   for (SiteEntry siteEntry : feedly.getEntries()){
       //for each entry grab the content feed
       ContentFeed contentFeed = 
       getContentFeed(sitesDomain, siteEntry.getSiteName().getValue());
   }

   //and then, iterate over each WebPageEntry (adding to an XML string)
   for (WebPageEntry entry : contentFeed.getEntries(WebPageEntry.class)) {
       log.error("Found web page  entry.");
       xmlString = "";
       xmlString += "<doc>";
       xmlString += "<title>" + entry.getTitle().getPlainText() + "</title>";
       xmlString += "</doc>";
   }//end of for loop
   ```

Essentially, after all this, the String "xmlString" is empty. It is as if it is trying to grab the content feed but something is stopping it.

I know that for this test site there is a couple of basic pages with simple text on them.

Can anyone help? Could this be the fact that my service account user does not have permissions to grab the Content Feed? Even though we are using a GoogleCredential that has previously allowed me to grab the Site Feed?

Perhaps there is a way to verify that the Content Feed has indeed been retrieved? Right now I just have an empty string!!

I would really appreciate any help you might be able to give.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think Google Sites API is old.
Look at Supported Google APIs.
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/

There isn't Google Sites API.
I recommend you to use Google Site Verification API, but it has less features than Google Sites API.